# pandas dataframe row background color

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm perplexed why below code won't change the background color.

```
  writer = ExcelWriter(path)
  df_delivery_style = df_delivery.style.apply(row_style, axis=1)

  df_delivery_style.to_excel(
         writer,
         columns=columns_delivery,
         index=False,
         engine='openpyxl',
     )
  writer.save()


 def row_style(row):
     if row['yellow']:

         return pd.Series('background-color: yellow', row.index)

     return pd.Series('', row.index)
```

I see one row has `row['yellow']` true. but on the resulting excel file, there's no yellow background.